# Angular - basic controller scope breaks code

Tags: angularjs

I have created a basic angular app on jsfiddle. However, whenever I add a `ng-controller`, my code breaks. Any idea what it could be ?

http://jsfiddle.net/up8pv/3/

Answer (score 1):

My actions:

1. added name for the module and initialized it explicitly via `angular.module()`
2. made sure that `RaffleCtrl` is proper function
3. changed jsFiddle type to be `No wrap - in <body>`

This has proven to fix the issue. I suggest you to investigate each one of this three hints to know for sure what the root of the evil was :)

http://jsfiddle.net/up8pv/5/

Comment: actually, I noticed that you had changed coffeescript to javascript. When I changed back to coffeescript, the problem re-appeared. Could it be that?

Comment: looks like it might have been all three, if I turn off one of the three options, it doesnt work! I'll investigate and let you know!

Comment: Great that you have made some progress. Sorry, I'm not an expert on `coffescript`, don't know if it can be a factor. One thing for sure - controller needs to be a function, not a `{}` like object.