# Automatic Initialization of Angular does not seem to work

Tags: angularjs

I was following the Automatic Initialization of Angular.js (based on their [example](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)) I made a basic html file, with the following contents:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="optionalModuleName">
  <body>
    I can add: {{ 1+2 }}.
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work on my browser. If I add the following script ([Manual Initialization](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)), it works.

```
<script>
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document);
});
</script>
```

I was wondering why automatic initialization did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You do not seem to have an `optionalModuleName` defined :-)

Comment: Ah, I see - thanks! (will mark your answer in 10 min when SO allows me to do so ;))

Comment: could you have a look at this too pls? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420858/angular-basic-controller-scope-breaks-code